# Объединение записей в одну строку из другой таблицы. MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Есть 3 таблицы
Первая - ФИЛЬМЫ (filmId, FilmName)
Вторая - АКТЕРЫ (actorID, FullName)
Третья - Связующая (filmID, actorID)

У фильма есть много актеров, потому я нуждаюсь в конкатенации имен Актеров, причастных к определенному фильму

К Примеру

Фильмы:

```
filmID  |  filmName
--------------------
    1   |    A
    2   |    B
```

Актеры:

```
actorId    |   FullName
-----------------------
     1     |  David
     2     |  Bill
     3     |  Steve
     4     |  Anna
```

И последняя:

```
filnId   |  actorId
-------------------
    1    |    1
    1    |    3
    2    |    2
    2    |    4
```

Нужно сделать вывод на подобии результата GROUP_CONCAT(), но в MS SQL SERVER такой функции нет

Пример вывода:

```
FilmName    |    Actors 
----------------------------
    A       |   David, Steve
    B       |   Bill,  Anna
```

Comment: *в MS SQL SERVER такой функции нет* [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Akina, другие аналоги есть? STRING_AGG тоже не распознает в моей версии. Я пробовал через STUFF(), но как-то не особо получилось

Comment: *STRING_AGG тоже не распознает в моей версии.* Вот даже после этого Вы так и не указали версию сервера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему самостоятельно таким вот запросом. 
Надеюсь, кому-то станет полезным

```
SELECT Name, ReleaseDate, 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [FullName] FROM Actors 
        JOIN Film_Actor ON Actors.actorID = Film_Actor.actorID
        WHERE filmID = F.filmID
        FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') Actors
FROM Films AS F;
```